# rhdfs - RJavaTools error writing datasets to hdfs

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs, rjava

I am running rStudio Server on a hortonworks sandbox version of hadoop.  I have the rhdfs package loaded, but when I try to write a dataset to hdfs using the hdfs.put() command I receive the following error:

```
hdfs.put(mtcars,"/user/root")
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.io.IOException: File c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5, 15.2, 13.3, 19.2, 27.3, 26, 30.4, 15.8, 19.7, 15, 21.4) does not exist
```

Anyone encountered this issue before?  I am assuming that it is related to using a 32 bit version of Java on a 64 bit operating system.  Any suggestions are much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Though its too late to answer, thought people might find this useful.

The command 'hdfs.put' of rhdfs package can be used to transfer files from the local file system to the HDFS. In this case mtcars is built in R data frame which has to be first saved to local disk before moving to hdfs using 'hdfs.put' command.

R Code:

```
# Save built in data set to local disk
save(mtcars, file = "/home/mtcars.RData")

# Move data from local to hdfs
hdfs.put("/home/mtcars.RData", "/in")
```